# Rails: Unable to link to images in assets/images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I'm attempting to accomplish here seems straightforward enough but has been a bit of a hassle. I'm just trying to access images that are within the assets/images directory via my browser. So, let's say I have a file whose location is

```
assets/images/my_file.png
```

You'd think one of the following would work:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/images/my_file.png
http://localhost:3000/assets/my_file.png
```

But neither does.

Is there something about the asset pipeline that I'm misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **rails 3 and 4**, you just get rid of the '**images**' part of the path. So an image that lives in **/assets/images/my_file.png** will actually be accessible in a get request at this url -**/assets/my_file.png**

Because the **assets/images** folder gets generated along with a new rails 4 app, this is the convention that they probably want you to follow. I think that's where image_tag will look for it, but I haven't tested that yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use this link:

localhost:3000/assets/my_file.png

Moreover,check whether you have used `<%=asset_path('my_file.png')%>` in your view or not. Hope this helps.